# Dynamic SQL Error -104 from Linked Firebird Database

Tags: sql-server, firebird, linked-server, firebird1.5

I have a SQL Server database and a Firebird database as a linked server.  I'm trying to select a table in the linked server, but I get the following error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FIREBIRD" returned message "[ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error
>
> SQL error code = -104
>
> Token unknown - line 1, column 22
>
> .".
>
> Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>
> Cannot open the table ""de_ib"."ROHSTOFF"" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FIREBIRD".

I have synonyms for the linked tables set up in my SQL database.  The following three statements all return this error:

```
SELECT * FROM ROHSTOFF
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ROHSTOFF]
SELECT * FROM [FIREBIRD].[de_ib]..[ROHSTOFF]
```

But the following returns the data as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(FIREBIRD, 'SELECT * FROM ROHSTOFF')
```

If I right-click a linked table and select Script Table as > INSERT To > New Query Editor Window, the following appears in the query editor:

```
-- [FIREBIRD].[de_ib]..[ROHSTOFF] contains no columns that can be selected or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
```

I'm logged in with credentials that match the owner of the Firebird database.

Why am I getting this error and how can I select data from my linked server without using OPENQUERY? I have a legacy application that selects from the Firebird database, but I need it to select seamlessly from the synonyms instead.

Comment: Possible help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741466/difference-between-a-linked-server-and-a-synonym

Comment: That does reflect my setup but doesn't explain why I'm getting the error.

Comment: It looks like the query that was generated contains `.".` at line 1, character 22, and this is a syntax error (token unknown basically means the statement sent to Firebird contains invalid syntax).

Comment: Given Firebird doesn't 'know' about existence of databases until you actually connect, nor has schemas, I'm wondering what `SELECT * FROM [FIREBIRD].[de_ib]..[ROHSTOFF]` actually means, and what it would get translated to (especially the `[de_ib]` and the two dots before `[ROHSTOFF]`).

Comment: [FIREBIRD].[de_ib]..[ROHSTOFF] is what's generated in SSMS when I drag the linked table into a query window.  I think this is because Firebird doesn't use the four-part naming that SQL uses.  de_ib is the name of the database in Firebird, while FIREBIRD is the name of the linked server.

Comment: Actually, that's not correct.  [FIREBIRD].[de_ib]..[ROHSTOFF] is what appears when I try to Script Table as > SELECT To > New Query Editor Window:

-- [FIREBIRD].[de_ib]..[DEBI_LAB_USERS] contains no columns that can be selected or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Comment: would you use Firebird 2.5 (can you upgrade engine?) then using TraceAPI and tools like FBProfiler.sf.net you would see verbatim queries MS SQL sends to Firebird. Actually, you may run FB 2.5 with the database on some another machine and temporarily route MS SQL there, just for intercepting exact verbatim queries from FB side and looking what was broken in them

Comment: I can't upgrade the Firebird database at the moment.